# Laravel pivot table bulk insert with multiple fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have a pivot table with fields:

- `language_id`
- `lesson_id`
- `name`
- `folder_path`
- `index_path`
- `download_path`

I need to update the table with this array of data. How can I achieve that?

This is my array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "language_id" => "17adbf30-9164-4a54-894c-17ad042123ae"
    "name" => "test"
    "folder_path" => "http://136.234.3.75/quest_admin"
    "download_path" => "http://136.234.3.75/quest_admin"
    "index_path" => "http://136.234.3.75/quest_admin"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "language_id" => "5fd19800-7bfd-465c-84a3-9267609b54bd"
    "name" => "test1"
    "folder_path" => "http://136.234.3.75/quest_admin"
    "download_path" => "http://136.234.3.75/quest_admin"
    "index_path" => "http://136.234.3.75/quest_admin"
  ]
]
```

This is my code:

```
$lesson->lessonLinks()->sync($request); 
// $request contains array of data for update pivot table
```

Comment: Read the documentation, it is pretty explanatory... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Answer (score 1):

I think You should Do something Like this

```
 $lesson->lessonLinks()->sync([$lesson_id=>[$request]]);
```